# not found in Multi language site with only session detection

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site with 3 enabled languages.
Default language is English
I've only setup my language options to use the "Session" detection method.
I dont to use URL language options.
when i create node in English node and set pathauto for url with token [node:author]/[node:content-type]/[node:nid]

is work in default language only when i switch language to another this token is not work.
for example when i create node in another language this path not work.

http://example.com/reza/news/324  this does not work (this node is created in arabic site)
http://example.com/ar/reza/news/324 this works but i don't want to user this url i want use this example http://example.com/reza/news/324?lan=ar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was resolved: When we create a new content type, the "Multilingual support" in "Publishing options" should be set to "Enabled, with translation."

[image: screenshot]
  [image: screenshot]